# display two arrays on uitableview sorted by date

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, twitter

I have two arrays one of which is a `tweets` array and contains twitter tweets. Another of which is a `instapics` array and contains Instagram pictures. Both of these Arrays have different keys for date. The twitter one had `created_at` and the instagram one has `created_time`. I want to display both of them on a single `UITableView` and have them organized by date. Here is what I am doing so far, the problem with this however is that it only shows Instagram Pictures:

```
- (void)sortArrayBasedOndate {
    NSDateFormatter *fmtDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [fmtDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSDateFormatter *fmtTime = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [fmtTime setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

    totalFeed = [totalFeed sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        // Instagram Date Retrieval
        NSDictionary *instagram = self.instaPics;
        NSString *createdAt = instagram[@"created_time"];
        int createdAtN = [createdAt intValue];
        NSTimeInterval timestamp = (NSTimeInterval)createdAtN;
        NSDate *date1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestamp];

        // Twitter Date Retrieval
        NSDictionary *twitter = self.tweets;
        NSString *twitterCreated = twitter[@"created_at"];
        int createdAtTwitter = [twitterCreated intValue];
        NSTimeInterval timestampTwitter = (NSTimeInterval)createdAtTwitter;
        NSDate *date2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestampTwitter];

        return [date1 compare:date2];
    }];
}
```

The above is how I am trying to organize them on the array, below is how I am attempting to display them:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id object = [totalFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([tweets containsObject:object]) {
        static NSString *Twitter = @"TweetCell";
        UITableViewCell *twitter = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Twitter];

        NSDictionary *totalArray = totalFeed[indexPath.row/2];;

// Creation Code Not shown

        return twitter;

    }else{
        static NSString *Instagram = @"InstagramCell";
        UITableViewCell *instagram = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Instagram];

    NSDictionary *entry = instaPics[indexPath.row / 2];
 // Creation Code not Shown
        return instagram;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your sort procedure isn't using the objects passed into it; it's not sorting the array correctly. I can't be certain, but it looks like it's sorting using the creation dates of the two feeds in their entirety.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Im sorry im new to iOS can you show me what to do?

Comment: Be more specific about what you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *easiest solution* would be if you add a common "creationDate" key to all objects in the 
`totalFeed` array. The value of this key should be an `NSDate` created from
the "created_at" or "created_time" key.
Then you can just sort the array according to this key:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];
totalFeed = [totalFeed sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
```

If you cannot do that for some reason, you have to fix the comparator method, it does
not use the passed arguments `obj1`, `obj2` at all.
Something like (pseudo-code):

```
totalFeed = [totalFeed sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSDate *date1, *date2;
    if ("obj1 is a Twitter") {
        date1 = "get created_at from twitter obj1"
    } else {
        date1 = "get created_time from instagram obj1"
    }
    if ("obj2 is a Twitter") {
        date2 = "get created_at from twitter obj2"
    } else {
        date2 = "get created_time from instagram obj2"
    }

    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

In any case, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you have to access `totalFeed[indexPath.row]`
(without dividing by 2, which does not make sense here).

---

More sample code:

```
NSArray *instaPics; // your instagrams
NSArray *tweets;    // your tweets
NSMutableArray *totalFeed = [NSMutableArray array]; // the common array

// Date formatter for the tweets. The date format must exactly
// match the format used in the tweets.
NSDateFormatter *fmtDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmtDate setDateFormat:@"..."];

// Add all instagrams:
for (NSMutableDictionary *instagram in instaPics) {
    NSString *createdAt = instagram[@"created_time"];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[createdAt doubleValue]];
    instagram[@"creationDate"] = date;
    [totalFeed addObject:instagram];
}
// Add all tweets:
for (NSMutableDictionary *twitter in tweets) {
    NSString *twitterCreated = twitter[@"created_at"];
    NSDate *date = [fmtDate dateFromString:twitterCreated];
    twitter[@"creationDate"] = date;
    [totalFeed addObject:twitter];
}

// Sort
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES];
[totalFeed sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
```

Comment: Could you please show me how I would create the common Creation Date key?

Comment: @prnk28: Are the twitter/instagram objects *dictionaries*?

Comment: Yes the objects are indeed Dictionaries

Comment: @prnk28: Even better. And created_at/created_time is stored as NSString or NSDate? If it is stored as string, how is it formatted?

Comment: It is created as a NSString and I manually formatted it as NSDates.

Comment: Actually the Twitter one is an NSString, and the Instagram one is an int. The int uses a datesince1970 timestamp

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44458/discussion-between-martin-r-and-prnk28)